# Calling a class in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have created in android studio an app that changes numbers from base 10 to base 2. I have created the algorithm below, but I have trouble calling the class and getting it to print the result.
Can anyone help me ? Thanks in advance.

This is my code,

```
public class baseconv {
    float m = Float.parseFloat(number.getText().toString());
    int n = (int) m;
    int pow = 1;
    int x = 0;

    public void calculate () {
        while (n > 0) {
            x = x + (n % 2)*pow;
            n = n / 2;
            pow = pow * 10;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your issue?

Answer (score 0):

To convert integer in base 10 to base 2 try this,

```
String baseTwoString = Integer.toString(your_integer, 2);
```

But if you are particular that you need to use your custom algorithm read on.

In your Activity,

```
String input = number.getText().toString();
try {
    int n = (int) Float.parseFloat(input);
    BaseConvert converter = new BaseConvert();
    int output = converter.calculate(n);
    Log.e("output : ", output);
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Your converter class,

```
public class BaseConvert {

    public int calculate (int n) {
        int pow = 1;
        int x = 0;
        while (n > 0) {
            x = x + (n % 2) * pow;
            n = n / 2;
            pow = pow * 10;
        }
        return pow;
    }

}
```